# UTFDataFormatException when trying to connect jvisualvm to an eclipse local process

Tags: java, exception, profiling, sampling, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile a local java application. It is run through Eclipse. I am using the jvisualvm corrsponding to my jdk installation. It sees the process when it is started, it can **sample** it without problem but when I try to start the **profiler**, the eclipse console shows this error :

```
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 15)
Profiler Agent: Established connection with the tool
Profiler Agent Error: Exception when trying to send response or command to client:
java.io.UTFDataFormatException
java.io.UTFDataFormatException
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:2007)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF(ObjectOutputStream.java:869)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.wireprotocol.VMPropertiesResponse.writeObject(VMPropertiesResponse.java:156)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.wireprotocol.WireIO.sendComplexResponse(WireIO.java:286)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer.sendComplexResponseToClient(ProfilerServer.java:678)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer.handleClientCommand(ProfilerServer.java:1559)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer.listenToClient(ProfilerServer.java:1698)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerServer.run(ProfilerServer.java:655)
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
```

When looking at the code, the `writeUTF` function throws this exception when the response is too long...

```
 void writeUTF(String s, long utflen) throws IOException {
            if (utflen > 0xFFFFL) {
                throw new UTFDataFormatException();
            }
...
}
```

Would someone have an idea about what happens here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running your Eclipse as Administrator? This sounds like a firewall issue and Eclipse does not have the necessary rights to ask for the firewall permission.

Comment: Yes I have tried running both tools as Administrator without any change. Also, our network administrator told me that the firewall does not block such localhost connections...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was likely caused by a [VisualVM bug](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/81)—now fixed—associated with long classpaths.